# Data imported into Overpass API lacks areas.bin?

Tags: overpass-api

I have installed Overpass locally following [official instructions](https://overpass-api.de/full_installation.html). I downloaded a small region data from [slaskie-latest.osm.bz2](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/poland/slaskie.html) and imported them into Overpass DB

```
bin/init_osm3s.sh slaskie-latest.osm.bz2 "^C/" "binaries/" --meta
```

The whole operation went fine with just some warnings:

```
compute_geometry: Way 539932453 used in relation 10072392 not found.
...
Flushing to database ....... done.
Update complete.
```

However, when I ask queries about areas, I keep gettings errors

```
~/overpass/osm-3s_v0.7.55$ binaries/bin/osm3s_query --db-dir=db/
encoding remark: Please enter your query and terminate it with CTRL+D.
 way(area:3602828735)["building"~"residential|house|terrace|detached|apartments|yes"];
    (._;>;);
    out body;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API 0.7.55.7 8b86ff77">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base=""/>


</osm>
runtime error: open64: 2 No such file or directory db/areas.bin File_Blocks::File_Blocks::1
```

In fact, db/ lacks areas.bin:

```
$ ls db
node_keys.bin             node_tags_local.bin.idx  relations_meta.bin.idx        ways.bin
node_keys.bin.idx         osm_base_version         relation_tags_global.bin      ways.bin.idx
nodes.bin                 relation_keys.bin        relation_tags_global.bin.idx  ways.map
nodes.bin.idx             relation_keys.bin.idx    relation_tags_local.bin       ways.map.idx
nodes.map                 relation_roles.bin       relation_tags_local.bin.idx   ways_meta.bin
nodes.map.idx             relation_roles.bin.idx   user_data.bin                 ways_meta.bin.idx
nodes_meta.bin            relations.bin            user_data.bin.idx             way_tags_global.bin
nodes_meta.bin.idx        relations.bin.idx        user_indices.bin              way_tags_global.bin.idx
node_tags_global.bin      relations.map            user_indices.bin.idx          way_tags_local.bin
node_tags_global.bin.idx  relations.map.idx        way_keys.bin                  way_tags_local.bin.idx
node_tags_local.bin       relations_meta.bin       way_keys.bin.idx
```

1. Is it because the region data lack information about areas or importwent wrong?
2. How can I resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Areas need to be created by a dedicated area creation step, which is separate from the initial database load. See the documentation on https://overpass-api.de/full_installation.html --> Area creation